# Function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, function

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to create a function that, when called, counts all the non-empty cells in the entered range that have that particular RGB color. I try using the function in my workbook, but I get #NAME? instead of a number in return.

```
Function countProspect(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Long

Dim cel As Variant

countProspect = 0
For Each cel In Range(rng1, rng2)
    If cel.Interior.Color = RGB(248, 203, 173) And IsEmpty(cel.Value) = False Then
        countProspect = countProspect + 1
    End If
Next cel

End Function
```

Comment: *Where* is this code? Is it in a standard module (where it should be) or in something like Sheet 1 code module (where it shouldn't be)?

Comment: Works for me if it is in the right place.

Comment: How are you using it? `=countProspect(A1,A10)` or `=countProspect(A1:A10)` ? It is written for the first version and wont work with the second. And this is pretty unusual for a UDF.

Comment: @A.S.H I think that the `#NAME?` error rather than something like a `#VALUE!` error points to a scoping problem. For large ranges it is sometimes useful to be able to enter them via clicking diagonally opposite corner points. An optimal solution could use a `ParamArray` and allow for either option.

Comment: @JohnColeman you're totally right, I had `#value` when trying to use it "wrongly" the way I suspected. Your diagnostic must be the right one.

Comment: @JohnColeman It's in a standard module. I've written functions before and used them successfully. I'm using a different computer than I usually do... maybe a setting is out of wack?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your code to support single or double input with Ranges of different size, this should do. It is also better to use Ranges, not just 2 single cell as the Function won't update when cells in between are changed.

e.g. If you have a cell `=countProspect(A3,C10)`, changes to `B4` will not update as *B4* is **not used** by *countProspect*. You need to consider this otherwise you get inaccurate results.

```
Option Explicit

Function countProspect(rng1 As Range, Optional rng2 As Range) As Long
    Dim allCell As Range, cel As Range, count As Long

    Set allCell = rng1
    If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then Set allCell = Union(allCell, rng2)
    For Each cel In allCell.Cells
        If cel.Interior.Color = RGB(248, 203, 173) And Not IsEmpty(cel) Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next cel
    countProspect = count
End Function
```